# Change language of app works in android studio, doesnt works when downloaded app from Google Play

Tags: android, locale

I need to change the app of my app. Im using this code:

```
private void saveLang() {
    if(prefs==null){
        prefs=getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("lang", lang);
    editor.apply();
    LocaleHelper.setLocale(ListActivity.this, lang);
}
```

And then, in every activity, I use this code:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
}
```

With this, the language change WORKS when I instale it from Android Studio...but DOESNT when I upload the .abb file and download the app from Google Play. Anybody knows why?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you get a solution to this? @fustigador

Answer (score 0):

When generating build as android app bundle, the language files are also spliced and that's why you maybe facing this issue. Try adding the following block to the **app level gradle** file inside the **android{}** block. Push a build to alpha or internal testing track to check if its working properly.

```
bundle {
    language {
        enableSplit = false
    }
}
```